# Uploading simple files to IPFS with oracles within the smart contract

Tags: oracles, ipfs

When I search google "How to upload files to IPFS within smart contract" I get the same answer: "You cannot do that. You need an oracle to do that" but no further information. Is there an oracle that I can use for IPFS uploads by connecting my smart contract? If not, where should I start to build one on my own?

Answer (score 0):

More of a keeper than an oracle on Ethereum.  (like an ittt service).  Oracles usually bring info on-chain.  I'm with Tellor and we can do IPFS proofs, but bringing them onto Ethereum. The other way around would be an oracle on the other ecosystem.  To get around this, I'd probably build it by having you upload it to IPFS and then have an oracle bring the data into your smart contract.